# CLLocationCoordinate2D converting return null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cllocationmanager, nsnumber

i m trying to convert longituude and latitude to NSNumbers to save them in core data.

following my code:

**getting coordinate**

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [[mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:0] coordinate];
    NSLog(@"Long2: %f", coordinate.longitude);
    NSLog(@"Lat2: %f", coordinate.latitude);
```

**Output**

```
2013-04-28 20:22:05.918 [1892:16a03] Long2: -122.406417
2013-04-28 20:22:05.918 [1892:16a03] Lat2: 37.785834
```

**Setting values:**

```
[members.eventDTO setLatLong:coordinate];
- (void)setLatLong: (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{
    self.locLatitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.latitude];
    self.locLongitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.longitude];
}
```

then i tried that for output:

```
NSLog(@"Long2: %f", [members.eventDTO.locLongitude doubleValue]);
NSLog(@"Lat2: %@", members.eventDTO.locLatitude);

2013-04-28 20:22:05.918 [1892:16a03] Long2: 0.000000
2013-04-28 20:22:05.919 [1892:16a03] Lat2: (null)
```

any clue its returning that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what you described in your question, it seems that the object is still nil after you set it in your `setLatLong:` method. My hints that I can suggest here are:

- try to log the NSNumber inside your `setLatLong:` method to check if they are being created correctly;
- try to log self.locLatitude and self.locLongitude after you set them, to see if they are assigned correctly.
- are the NSManagedObject being created correctly?
- are you calling save to your NSManagedObjectContext?

Please post more info so we can hunt the problem together ;)

Comment: good hint about that with nil.. i m passing data between views and my DTO object was not initialized .. well with your hint you saved my night so ty  and accepted ;)